# How to have both original message and redelivery counter in a Camel dead letter route

Tags: java, apache-camel, dead-letter

I have a Camel route configured with a dead letter channel like this:

```
from(...)
  .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("vm:deadLetter")
    .useOriginalMessage()
    .retryWhile(method(new BadMessageRuleset(redeliveryTimes), "shouldRetry"))
    .maximumRedeliveries(redeliveryTimes)
    .redeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelayInitial)
    .backOffMultiplier(redeliveryDelayMultiplier)
  ...

from("vm:deadLetter")
    .bean(deadLetterService)
    .end();
```

It's working fine but now I need to save the number of redeliveries occurred before when a message is sent to dead letter channel.  Note that I'm using useOriginalMessage(), so this is the message I want to be save in dead letter channel (yes! my route changes it on the way).

I tried to access the number of redeliveries in the message header Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER, but it is always null when the message reaches the deadLetterService bean.  I do understand that is so because original message do not have this header information.

How could I keep the redelivery counter and restore the original message in exchange at the same time?  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Heleno

Comment: The message would be redelivered as many times as you have specified in maximumRedeliveries. So the REDELIVERY_COUNTER prior to being sent to deadletter queue should always be the same as maximumRedeliveries. Unless you manually send this message to deadletter queue in your route?

Comment: From Camel 2.16 onwards you can use the onPrepareFailure - http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri, the problem is that I use also retryWhile().  So the message can be sent to deadletter before maximumRedeliveries() is reached.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I'm using Camel 2.15, but I think onPrepareFailure() will solve my problem.  Please, place your comment as an answer. ;-)